# 溶液に浸したリトマス試験紙の画像からpHを測りたい

Tags: opencv

溶液に浸したリトマス試験紙の画像を画像解析で「pH」を測りたいです。なにか良い方法はないでしょうか。
試験紙の色をどう抽出するか質問の対象外となります。

自分の中では下記で実現できるのではないかと考えています。
・予めPHごとの色をLabで持っておく（色見本と呼ぶことにします）。
・反応した試験紙の色をLabで取得し、DE2000 などで色見本と試験紙の色を比較し、差異が最も近いものを pH とする

他に良い意見がありましたら教えていただけたらと思います。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 参考:[Evaluation of pH Value by Using Image Processing](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/132/app132z3-IIp086.pdf)

Comment: @metropolis 期待と合致した情報だと思いました。ありがたく確認させていただきます。 紹介ありがとうございました。